# How can I change sound depth and frequency characteristics in GarageBand?

Tags: garageband

How can I change depth (bits) and frequency (kHzs) characteristics when recording session in GarageBand?

If I can't then what are the default values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change depth and frequency of the recorded samples, even when changing the input settings in the `Audio MIDI Setup.app` (this is the way to change playback and recording settings for sound devices).
[image: Audio Devices setup in Audio MIDI Setup.app]
The default values for Garage Band are 44kHz, 16 bit, stereo. They are kept in AIFF format. You can explore them by right-clicking your garage band project and choosing `Show package contents`. The recorded files are kept in the `Media` folder.

*Edit (added Logic 9):*
In Logic 9 you can change the sampling rate (frequency) from the `Project Settings` window, `Audio` tab. Explained in the [Logic 9 Manual - Setting the Sample rate](http://documentation.apple.com/en/logicpro/usermanual/#chapter=14%26section=2). To change the bit depth you should go to `Preferences` -> `Audio` and check/uncheck `24 bit recording` (It's checked by default). It's covered in the [Logic 9 Manual - Setting the project bit depth](http://documentation.apple.com/en/logicpro/usermanual/#chapter=14%26section=3).

Comment: Thanks, brilliant answer. And maybe you know, could I change those values in Logic?

Comment: @NR4TR I don't have Logic, but it's in the manual - yes you can. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Cool, thanks again. It's a pity that I cannot upvote again :)

Answer (score 0):

Using TechTools Pro you can manipulate the default audio frequency.

[image]